# Error running Powershell script from a .csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a PowerShell script using the information contained within a .csv file.

My script is below:

```
Import-CSV \\chem-fp01\shared areas\IT\New IT Folder (Do Not Delete \\Powershell Scripts\Create New User.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force

  New-Mailbox -Name $_.Name
  -FirstName $_.FirstName
  -LastName $_.LastName
  -Alias $_.Alias
  -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName
  -Password $password
  -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false 
}
```

I am getting the error below and don't know what it means

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At C:\Scripts\CreateNewUser.psl:7 char:3
+ - <<<<LastName $_.LastName
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to either, write all parameters to one line:

```
New-Mailbox -Name $_.Name -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -Alias $_.Alias -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -Password $password -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false
```

Or you can use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) (Thanks [Frode F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702944/frode-f)):

```
$parameters = @{
    Name = $_.Name 
    FirstName = $_.FirstName 
    LastName = $_.LastName 
    Alias = $_.Alias 
    UserPrincipalName = $_.UserPrincipalName 
    Password = $password 
    ResetPasswordOnNextLogon = $false 
}

New-Mailbox @parameters
```

Another solution would be to use the ` character at the end of the line (**not recommended**)  :

```
New-Mailbox -Name $_.Name `
-FirstName $_.FirstName `
-LastName $_.LastName `
-Alias $_.Alias `
-UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
-Password $password `
-ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false
```

Comment: Thank you...what do you mean by character at the end of the line?

Comment: If your cmdlet invocation spawns multiple lines, you have to tell PowerShell using the ` symbol, that the next line belongs to the line above.

Comment: Thank you.  I have put the ` at the end of each line as you said.  However, now I am getting the following error.  Missing closing `>` in statement block.  At C:\scripts\createNewUser.ps1:15 char:1 *<<<<  *CategoryInfo     :  ParserError:  <CloseBraceToken:TokenId> [], ParseException   *FullyQualifiedErrorID:  MissingEndCurlyBrace

Comment: As the error message tells you, you are missing the `}` at the end. I will just edit my answer so you can copy paste it...

Comment: Please do not recommend using backticks. Backticks are evil. Use splatting or the normal one-line way.

Comment: @FrodeF. Ah, I should have mentioned splatting! Can you explain why backticks are evil? I didn't know that (even I barely use them)

Comment: Because they're hard to see and if a single one is removed, lost in copy/paste etc, everything breaks down. It's a hack, not a feature. Backticks are designed for escaping characters inside a string. :)

Comment: Thank you jisaak.  I apologize for all of the back and forth.  I found some other issues which I fixed.  When I run it now it says it Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.  *CategoryInfo  :InvalidData: <:> [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingValidationException   *FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArugument ValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,New-Mailbox

Comment: I then checked the CSV and the name is populated so it is not an empty string...I am confused by the error

Comment: Use PowerShell ISE to debug your script and ensure the $_.Name is set. If you still have issues, please start a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this command fails, is because your CSV file path contains spaces, and you are not surrounding it with double or single quotes.

Whenever your path contains blank spaces, just add quotes at the beginning and end of the path like this:

```
Import-CSV "\\chem-fp01\shared areas\IT\New IT Folder (Do Not Delete \\Powershell Scripts\Create New User.csv"
```